# boost::asio sync server is not accepting connections after first one

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am writing simple synchronous asio server.
Workflow is following - in endless cycle accept connections and create thread for each connection. I know, this is not so optimal, but async is too hard for me.

Here's my ugly code:

```
std::vector<asio::io_service*> ioVec;
std::vector<std::thread*> thVec;
std::vector<CWorker> workerVec;
std::vector<tcp::acceptor*> accVec;

while (true) {
    ioVec.emplace_back(new asio::io_service());
    accVec.emplace_back(new tcp::acceptor(*ioVec.back(), tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 3228)));
    tcp::socket* socket = new tcp::socket(*ioVec.back());
    accVec.back()->accept(*socket);
    workerVec.push_back(CWorker());
    thVec.emplace_back(new std::thread(&CWorker::run, &workerVec.back(), socket));
}
```

The problem is first connection being done, it's correctly accepted, thread is created, and everything is good. Breakpoint is correctly triggered on "accept()" string. But if I want to create second connection (it does not matter if first is DCed or not) -> telnet is connected, but breakpoint on next string to "accept" is not triggered, and connection is not responding to anything.

All this vector stuff - I've tried to debug somehow to create separate acceptor, io_service for any connection - not helped. Could anyone point me where is error?

P.S. Visual Studio 2013

Comment: It is highly unusual to need more than one io_service. A single io_service reacts to events occurring on multiple ports (or other sources of asynchronous events.)  Hence I question the need for ioVec.

Comment: previously it was 1 io_service, 1 acceptor. Instead of simply hanging it throwed some obscure error in code. So, this looks not related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general pattern for an asio-based listener is:

```
// This only happens once!
create an asio_service
create a socket into which a new connection will be accepted
call asio_service->async_accept passing 
       the accept socket and 
       a handler (function object)  [ see below]
start new threads (if desired.  you can use the main thread if it 
   has nothing else to do)
Each thread should:
    call asio_service->run [or any of the variations -- run_one, poll, etc]

Unless the main thread called asio_service->run() it ends up here 
"immediately"  It should do something to pass the time (like read
from the console or...)   If it doesn't have anything to do, it probably
should have called run() to make itself available in the asio's thread pool.
```

In the handler function:

```
  Do something with the socket that is now connected.
  create a new socket for the next accept
  call asio_service->async_accept passing 
       the new accept socket and 
       the same handler.
```

Notice in particular that each accept call only accepts one connection, and you should not have more than one accept at a time listening on the same port, so you need to call async_accept again in the handler from the previous call.

Boost ASIO has some very good tutorial examples like [this one](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3.html)

Comment: Yep, each accept call accepts one connection, then cycle rewinds, new acceptor creates and next connection is accepted. This is how it is supposed to work - but it's not.

Comment: It appears to me that you are firing up many asio services each with one handler and each serviced by one thread, but all of them are trying to listen on the same port at the same time.  You should only have one outstanding accept at a time -- that's why you start the new accept in the handler for the previous one.

Comment: Previously I've used 1 acceptor and 1 io_service, but this did not work either. But instead of hanging - it throw some obscure error. I think, something in my code is missing, but not many asio-related stuff\calls...

Comment: Just as a suggestion:  Try my answer (you'll have to write the actual code) or try the ASIO tutorial (the code is already written at the link I referenced in my answer).  If that works then you have a working example that you can compare to your code.

Comment: Oh, and "some obscure error" is probably your problem.  Spend the time to print the error message and read it.  ASIO's errors are rarely obscure.  I'm betting that the error will say the listen port is busy because you are trying to listen on it more than once at the same time.